# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on an erb array iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Im currently working in an Rails 5 application where you can search for a first name or last name and records of the customers of that account would be displayed. However I am getting a Nil object return from search algorithm.

customers_controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:keywords].present?
      @keywords = params[:keywords]
      customer_search_term = CustomerSearchTerm.new(@keywords)
      @customer = Customer.where(
        customer_search_term.where_clause,
        customer_search_term.where_args).
        order(customer_search_term.order)
    else
      @customers = []
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see if there is no records found is suppose to return an empty array but is returning a Nil object.

customers/index.html.erb

```
[![<header>
  <h1 class="h2">Customer Search</h1>
</header>

<section class="search-form">
  <%= form_for :customers, method: :get do |f| %>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <%= label_tag :keywords, nil, class: "sr-only" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :keywords, nil,
                          placeholder: "First Name, Last Name or Email Address",
                          class: "form-control input-lg" %>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <%= submit_tag "Find Customers", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
      </span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</section>

<section class="search-results">
  <header>
    <h1 class="h3">Results</h1>
  </header>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Joined</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= customer.email %></td>
          <td><%= l customer.created_at.to_date %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should understand is that instance variables return `nil` if they haven't been set. If you say `@fake_var == nil` it will be true if you never defined `@fake_var` before this. You can contrast this with regular local variables, which will raise a NoMethodError if you try and use them before they're defined. For example, `puts(fake_var)` will raise a NoMethodError for fake_var.

Now look at your template. No matter what it will loop over `@customers`. If `@customers` has not been set, you'll see a NoMethodError because you can't call `each` on `nil`.

Finally, look at your controller action:

```
  def index
    if params[:keywords].present?
      @keywords = params[:keywords]
      customer_search_term = CustomerSearchTerm.new(@keywords)
      @customer = Customer.where(
        customer_search_term.where_clause,
        customer_search_term.where_args).
        order(customer_search_term.order)
    else
      @customers = []
    end
  end
```

Specifically the case when `params[:keywords].present?`. You never set `@customers` in this case so it will be `nil` when the template tries to access it.

I think if you simply replaced `@customer =` with `@customers =` it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can force it to return array using #to_a which converts nil to empty array

```
def index
  return [] unless params[:keywords]
  @keywords = params[:keywords]
  customer_search_term = CustomerSearchTerm.new(@keywords)
  @customer = Customer.where(
    customer_search_term.where_clause,
    customer_search_term.where_args).
    order(customer_search_term.order
  ).to_a
end
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/to_a